# Como enviar uma mensagem através do Messenger do Facebook?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Android que necessita enviar uma mensagem através do Messenger do Facebook.

Minha aplicação já esta integrada ao WhatsApp... pelo Whats eu sempre verifico se existe o aplicativo instalado, se sim, abro com a mensagem já formatada e só é preciso escolher o contato.

Gostaria de fazer o mesmo com o Messenger, alguém sabe como ????

Obrigado!

Obs.: Ja vi aqui algo relacionado a isso, porem em JavaScript.

Comment: A sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Comece por ler [isto](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android) e se tiver alguma dificuldade especifica ao implementar actualize a pergunta.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android    penso que isso irá ajudar :p

Comment: ok. Vou tentar implementar pelo link! Obrigado!